# How to create / use a 'Non Generic Queue'

Tags: c#, data-structures, queue

I am currently using a standard queue. Unfortunately I also want to know when items are enqueued and dequeued and I am unable to do this with a generic queue (queue).

According to another thread on here I need a 'non generic queue' so I am able to override the enqueue and dequeue methods so event handlers can be used.

Please note I have looked at observable collection, what I require is a observable queue 'like' data structure.

How do I create this 'non generic queue'?

Is it a part of a library?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you maybe paste some sample code so we may get some better context?

Comment: Why not just *encapsulate* the queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're talking about this [`Queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

And yes, the Enqueue and Dequeue methods are virtual, so you'll be able to override them and do something like this:

```
public class ObservableQueue : Queue
{
    public event EventHandler<QueueChangedArgs> OnChanged;

    public override void Enqueue(object obj)
    {
        base.Enqueue(obj);
        if (OnChanged != null)
            OnChanged(this, new QueueChangedArgs(obj, QueueEventType.ItemEnqueued));
    }
}

public enum QueueEventType { ItemEnqueued, ItemDequeued }
public class QueueChangedArgs : EventArgs
{
    public object Item { get; private set; }
    public QueueEventType EventType { get; private set; }

    public QueueChangedArgs(object item, QueueEventType type)
    {
        Item = item;
        EventType = type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do I create this 'non generic queue'?
>
> Is it a part of a library?

you should  add the name space it's base class in  mscorlib.dll

```
using System.Collections;
```